# How to copy only the files of a folder(including subfolder's files), but not the folder itself in shell

Tags: shell, ssh, scp

In Openssh, On the client, the content of path/to/file must be copied to Server. All files in
/path/to/file on the client must be copied to /path/to/files on the server. Note: only copy files, no folders! and files of subfolders. please give the command.

Comment: scp –r user@server:/path/to/file/* /path/to/file.. but the result is that desired_folder is not a regular file. and in this folder i want all the files to be copied. but not the desired_folder.

Comment: maybe you should read the man page for `scp` and not just add random options. `-r` means recursively copy entire directories, kind of strange to add that to `scp` if that is not what you want.

Comment: yes.. thats okey. i had removed that. but still it is not being copied.what about the result that its not a regular file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
scp /path/to/file/* user@server:/path/to/files/
```

it will complain about not copying directories.

If you want to copy the files in the directories under `/path/to/`, you can do:

```
scp /path/to/*/* user@server:/path/to/files/
```

Comment: but i want the files of the directories to be copied.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the `GLOBIGNORE='*/.:*/..:dirname1:dirname2'` to exclude the specified directories from the `*` glob? And then:

```
scp -r /path/to/file/* user@server:/path/to/files/
```

Comment: but in above command the folder is also being copied,that is not desired man